# Appending script with document.write synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronous

I've encountered a problem when appending script to html. Here is a sample code:

```
<script>$('body').append("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/localtest\/test.php\"><\/script>");</script>
```

**test.php source**

```
<?php sleep(1); ?>
document.write('<div></div>');
```

HTML inside `append` function can be any html, not necessarly a script. It works unless I got HTML mentioned in example.

**Result**

JS code from test.php is not executed because it's blocked by browser (I'm using FF): "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."

I'm not able to modify test.php content, it's loaded from external server.

Wy it is executed async? How to force sync execution?

Comment: Use `document.write()` instead of `$('body').append()` to load the script synchronously.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of document.writes from my script, so it can also be loaded async.

Comment: Then why are you asking "*How to force sync execution?*" if you don't want that???

Comment: I meant I want to get rid of document.writes są my code is also async friendly, and anyone using my code won't get same error as I get.

Comment: Then just remove the `document.write('<div></div>')` from the script and use something like `$('body').append('<div></div>')` instead?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I can't modify content of test.php, as it is loaded from external server.

Comment: Well if you want to "*get rid of `document.write`*" and "*make your code async friendly*", then you cannot load that `test.php` that uses `document.write`. Make whoever maintains that external server fix their script. Or proxy it if they refuse. Or overwrite `document.write` as a last resort.

Comment: I've implemented use of https://github.com/krux/postscribe as indirect solution. Works in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use

```
$(window).ready(function() {
     //put your code here
});
```

berfore appending.

So, complete code would be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
         $('body').append("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/localtest\/test.php\"><\/script>");
    });
</script>
```